# How to merge bookmark files?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, bookmarks

Due to the death of my laptop, I've decided to extract its hard disc and turn it into an external drive. Since I had a metric ton of bookmarks there, I'm afraid that plugging the disc in another computer will overwrite them. Will that happen, and if yes, how do I avoid it?

Comment: Bookmarks for what browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it as a secondary drive this should not happen, you would need to go search for the bookmark file/files to import them into your current browser. If you're using it as a main drive it should also not be an issue as it's the main drive meaning it'll be your main browser.